# ¿Como hacer que se muestre de un color una fila en consulta SQL?

Tags: html, sql, web

Tengo una consulta SQL en una aplicación web, lo que quiero mostrar es que las filas de con `total = 100` se muestren de color `verde` y las filas con `total = 0` se muestren en color `rojo`, pero no se como implementar esta función.

¿Me podrían ayudar?

```
               <%
consulta conexion = new consulta ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","pasaportes","oppasaportes");
    String consulta = "SELECT id_delegacion, CONTRATO   , prerequisitos_tecnologicos, equipamiento, sistema_operacion, privilegios, capacitacion, citas FROM delegaciones";

   ResultSet rs = conexion.ejeSelect(consulta);
     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
           int col= rsmd.getColumnCount();           
                 for(int k=1;k<=col;k++){          
            %>                                       
            <td><h9> <%= rsmd.getColumnName(k) %></h9></td>
            <%
                            }      
            %>                               
        </tr>         

        <%
         while(rs.next()){
        %>
        <tr class="info"> 

            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(2) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(3) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(4) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(5) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(6) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(7) %></h6> </td>
            <td><h6><%= rs.getString(8) %></h6> </td>



        </tr>   
        <%
                   }
        %>
            </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Si es una tabla dinámica, en el programa con el que llenas tu tabla le pones una condición en la cual le de un nombre de clase o un id a la fila cuando el valor sea = 100 y otro cuando =0 y luego por CSS le das el color que quieras.Si es una tabla fija lo haces manualmente.

Comment: @lois6b Ya añadi mi código, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @A.Cedano es dinaimica mi tabla, contiene boostrap.

Comment: Hice un comentario en la respuesta existente sobre cómo deberías hacerlo Javascript no es una buena opción ya que podría estar desactivado del lado del cliente. Y porque además no hay por qué **recorrer** de nuevo la tabla. Cuando la creas dinámicamente preguntas por el valor si es 0 le asignas un id a esa fila y si es 100 le asignas otro id y luego por CSS cambias los colores.

Comment: @MannyBrenes, de tu `SELECT`, ¿cuál es la columna que usas para el total?, ¿es `citas`?. Tambien te recomiendo organizar tu código. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como has dicho que es una tabla dinámica, en el programa con el que llenas tu tabla pones una condición en la cual le de un nombre de clase o un id a la fila cuando el valor sea = 100 y otro cuando = 0 y luego por CSS le das el color que quieras.

Te dejo un ejemplo en el cual se cambia el color de toda la fila. Cuando el valor sea cero el elemento tr sería así: `<tr id="cero">...</tr>` y si es cien sería  `<tr id="cien">...</tr>` , luego, por CSS se cambia el color de toda la fila simplemente con esto: `.info tr#cero { color:red; }`, si sólo quieres cambiar el color de una columna, sería con esto: `.info td#cero { color:red; }` y en ese caso asignaría el id="cero" o id="cien" no a toda la fila, sino a la columna específica que quieres cambiar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tabla</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .info tr, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }

 .info tr#cero { color:red; }

 .info tr#cien {color: green; }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="info">
<!-- Si el valor es cero se asigna un id="cero" a tr -->
    <tr id="cero">
        <td>rs.getString(1) es 0</td>
        <td>rs.getString(2) es 0</td>
        <td>etc... es 0</td>
    </tr>
<!-- Si el valor normal, entonces tr normal -->
    <tr>
        <td>rs.getString(1) no es 0 ni 100</td>
        <td>rs.getString(2) no es 0 ni 100</td>
        <td>etc... no es 0 ni 100</td>
    </tr>
<!-- Si el valor es 100, entonces tr con id=cien -->
    <tr id="cien">
        <td>rs.getString(1) valor es 100</td>
        <td>rs.getString(2) valor es 100</td>
        <td>etc... valor es 100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias fue de muchísima ayuda su respuesta, Gracias por todo y a todos, buen día.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar javascript para recorrer la tabla y asignarle un color te pongo un ejemplo que tienes que ajustar un poco a tu tabla

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargar() {
    var celdas = document.getElementById("target").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var i=0; i<celdas.length; i++) {
        if(celdas.item(i).textContent >=3 && celdas.item(i).textContent <=8) {
            celdas.item(i).style.color = "#F00";
        }
    }
}

window.onload = cargar;
</script>
```

Comment: Ya lo modifique pero no da resultados, la tabla se muestra igual.

Comment: Puedes añadir como has modificado y miramos que esta fallando y donde estas introduciendo el codigo

Comment: solo cambie los valores de >=3 a >=1 y el <=8 a <=98
y el código lo puse encima de la consulta, aparte.

Comment: ¿Y si Javascript no funciona o está desactivado del lado del cliente? Los cambios no aplicarían. Lo que hay que hacer es añadir dos condiciones cuando se crea la tabla en el bucle: si valor =0 <tr id="cero">...</tr> y luego si valor =100: <tr id="cien">...</tr> y luego das color  a través de CSS: #cero: color:red; #cien: color:green; y listo. No veo por qué complicarse la vida con JS.

Comment: muchas gracias por todo!!
seguiré intentando solucionarlo. :)

Answer (score 0):

También puede usar jQUERY para la validación de colores y negritas

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        h1 { text-align: center;}
    </style>
<title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<h1>validacion por color</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">Valores</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">cantidad</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center">valor1</td>
          <td class ="valor"> 100 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center" >valor2</td>
          <td class ="valor">7500 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center">valor3</td>
          <td class="valor"> 250</td>
        </tr>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".valor").parent("tr").find(".valor").each(function(){
          
                if($(this).html() <= 100 ) {
                    $(this).css("background-color","#C6CFFF");
                } else{
                  $(this).css("background-color","#ACF3FD");
                }
          
              });
              $(".valor").parent("tr").find(".valor").each(function(){
                
                if($(this).html() > 101 ) {
                    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
                }
              });
            });
          </script>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```